# Regex stripping start and end of string

Tags: python, regex, opentsdb

I have an OpenTSDB query and I want to extract the metric from it. The queries are of the format `(x:)<METRIC_NAME>{<OPTIONS>}`

An example query is `15-min-sum:rate:proc.stat.cpu{host=foo,type=idle}`

I want to extract the `proc.stat.cpu` part.

[Here's what I have so far.](https://regex101.com/r/4aIVLr/3) How do I catch the end of the string in the same regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query string is going to be of exact same format, this might work.

```
str = "15-min-sum:rate:proc.stat.cpu{host=foo,type=idle}"
print(str[str.rfind(":")+1 : str.find("{")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Group 2 and Group 3 from `^(\w\W*)*:(.*){(.*)}$` will capture `proc.stat.cpu` and the options respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://regex101.com/r/4aIVLr/4
```

15-min-sum:rate:proc.stat.cpu{host=foo,type=idle}

```
(?![\w-]*:)([\w\.]*)({.*})
creates two group
```

proc.stat.cpu

{host=foo,type=idle}